# No way to write a commercial product in R?

Tags: licensing, gpl, commercial, linked-libraries

I want to write a small program in the R language, connecting to DB (hence using packages), that I'd like to sell.

As it will connect to DB, on internal networks, that can't be hosted.

I tried to replace all GPL-alike packages to MIT ones... but R in itself is GPL.

Does that mean that I can't write a program, and sell it, at all in R?

**UPDATE --** To be sure that the program won't be easily copied, or played with, I do want / need to keep the sources closed.  For example, to hinder anyone from commenting the code about the need for a valid product key.

**Bonus:** Is there a template for "commercial use" licenses?

Comment: The GPL license doesn't stop you making commercial products at all, so I don't understand what issue you think there is.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've added an UPDATE section to clarify the point that was missing: about closed sources. Making them open would allow anybody to just remove the need for a public keep, or to publish the code somewhere.

Comment: s/need for a public keep/need for a public key/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because a language and its toolchains are licensed under the GNU GPL does not mean that any software you create with it also needs to be GPL-licensed. The [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF) reads:

> **Can I use GPL-covered editors such as GNU Emacs to develop nonfree programs? Can I use GPL-covered tools such as GCC to compile them?**
>
> Yes, because the copyright on the editors and tools does not cover the code you write. Using them does not place any restrictions, legally, on the license you use for your code.

But you still have to be careful with the libraries you are using. When you create a program which uses a GPL library, then the whole program needs to be GPL.

Comment: I really can't make my way out of this.

As stated in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#:~:text=R%20is%20released%20under%20the,version%202%20or%20version%203.&text=It%20is%20the%20opinion%20of,any%20use%20of%20the%20package, "GPL [only] restricts distribution of R or of other programs containing code from R."

Comment: Also, I'm reading comments such as "R is GPL. Going to lengths to use non-GPL packages is a great endeavor, but if you're somehow using R to use those packages, then you're using GPL" (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478810/mit-licensed-alternative-to-knitr); IIUC, that forces me to disclose the sources, doesn't it?

Comment: I want to add that R is an interpreted language, hence the program we write can't be compiled to a standalone executable file.

Comment: @Seb The R interpreter is a program covered by GPL. Your program runs on the R interpreter, but does not include code from the R interpreter. Your program and the R interpreter do not form a single program, so you are not affected by the interpreter's GPL license. However, your program will effectively include any loaded libraries. The comment on the deleted SO question seems incorrect.

Comment: @amon Thx for your comments/answers. 2 questions:

1. My idea was to package (with InnoSetup) R-portable with my lib, so that there would be nothing to do for the user, but extract that package, containing everything needed.  Is that a bad idea, then?  As I would distribute the R interpreter with my library. Should I instead need the ask the user to install R on his own, and then simply download my package in the right directory?

2. What's the diff between R-interpreter and 3rd-party packages? I need both for my prg to run... so I don't really see the distinction of treatment.

Comment: @Seb 1. You're perfectly allowed to distribute a GPL program alongside a non-GPL program. This is called [mere aggregation](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html#MereAggregation). Of course, you'll have to comply with GPL with respect to the GPL components, e.g. provide source code. 2. Some argue that there is no difference :) The question isn't what your program *needs*, but whether it is a derivative work in the sense of copyright law. The R authors don't have copyright in your scripts, just like Microsoft doesn't hold copyright for all novels written in Word.

Comment: @amon, so, to sum up, what you say is that I may build a commercial product in R, that uses R packages. I can sell it, and I can keep the sources of my program closed. I can also distribute the whole program using R-portable (a folder containing the R interpreter and the needed libraries). Is this right?

Comment: Finally, should I better use R packages which do have Apache or MIT licenses?  Or that does not really matter: like for the R interpreter, I could use GPL R packages?

Comment: @Seb You can build a closed-source product on R, but you need to take care with libraries. If you use GPL libraries, you'd likely have to license your code under GPL as well. So you'd have to stick to Apache/MIT/… licenses, which will be difficult in the R ecosystem. Frankly, R is a good platform for (explorative) data science but a really bad platform for a customer-facing product, not just because of licensing concerns. But yes, using a portable R installation would work, provided that your code is kept clearly separate and that you comply with the licenses of R and all libraries.

Comment: @amon, just for my information, which language would you then advice, for writing a problem that must connect to different DBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.), manipulate data frames resulting from the SQL requests, save them in XLS files and send emails, to name a few needed functionalities?  (PS- Thanks a lot for your extensive explanation!)